# How to duplicate all words which are not repeated in a given string?

Tags: c, text, strtok

I need to duplicate all words which are not repeating in a string, and put the duplicate after that word.

For example:

- Input text: "I need repeat need"
- Desired output: "I I need repeat repeat need"

I can't get how to compare the words in the string. Here's my code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    system("cls");
          char stri[200],*sad;
          int lenght1 = 0;
          int i;
    printf("Please input string\n");
    gets(stri);
    sad=strtok(stri," ,.!?");
    while(sad!=0)
    {

        printf("%s\n",sad);
        sad=strtok(NULL, " .,!?");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of the top of my head, first store every word in a list, in the order you get them (so you can print it out in the correct order again). Then go through the list, checking for duplicates of each word, and if one is found set a flag on the two word nodes. Finally write out the words in the list, twice if the word does not have the "multiple" flag set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need two data structures: one to allow quick traversal over the string by word, and another for quick lookup to see if the word has been encountered yet.

Use a binary search tree ([tutorial](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_bst1.aspx)) for the quick lookup.  Writing one yourself is a worthwhile exercise in C if you are starting out.  Or use a [trie](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/trie/) if you need more speed.  Each node will store a `char *` for the word and a `size_t` for the count.

Build a linked list to traverse the string by word.  Go along the input string using `strtok` to break it into words, like you are already doing.  As you tokenize, build up a linked list where each node contains a pointer to the beginning of its word.  Insert each word to the binary search tree to keep track of its count.

When you're done, go back through the beginning of the linked list.  Iterate over each word and look up its count in the binary search tree.  If it is `1`, print it twice, otherwise print it once.

Should be about 200 lines of C if you write the data structures yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little modified function of mine from C++ (it used `std::string` and `std::vector` there), so I'm sorry for the possible errors, but here's a `split` function using `strtok` that you can use:

```
int split(char *results, int resultsDim, char* toSplit, const char *delims){
    char *tmpString;
    int beginning = 0;
    int num = 0, i=0;
    int len = strlen(toSplit);

    for (tmpString = strtok(toSplit, delims), i=0;
        tmpString != NULL; tmpString = strtok(NULL, delims), ++i){
            strncpy((results+(num++)*resultsDim), tmpString, strlen(tmpString));
            (results+(num-1)*resultsDim)[i-beginning] = 0;
            beginning = i+1;
    }    

    if (beginning != len){
        strncpy((results+(num++)*resultsDim), tmpString, strlen(tmpString));
        (results+(num-1)*resultsDim)[len-beginning] = 0;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Now, you can use the function to get the number of tokens and tokens in a separate string array, iterate through that and follow the general @Joachim Pileborgs idea, like this:

```
int main(void){

    int n;
    char words[20][50+1];
    char flags[20] = {0};
    char sentence[50*20+1];
    int i, j;

    printf("Get me the input: \n");
    fgets(stdin, sentence, 50*20);

    n = splitString((char*)words, 50+1, sentence, " .,!?");

    for (i=0; i < n; ++i)
        for (int j=0; j < n; ++j)
            if (!strcmp(words[i], words[j]))
                ++flags[j];

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        printf("%s ", words[i]);
        if (flags[i] > 1)
            printf("%s ", words[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Btw, you should note that I used `fgets` instead of `gets` function to input the sentence in the beginning: That's because `gets` is generally considered *unsafe*. That is, if the input string is *longer* than the memory reserved for the string, it will just continue writing data it memory that has not been reserved. `fgets`, on the contrary, has an extra argument saying what is the maximum number of useful characters (not counting `'\0'`) it can input - and thus, it will definitely stay in the bounds of the reserved memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map to hash the words. It would now be easier to accomplish the task of checking for repeated words.
Then, in a second pass you can give the desired output.

Comment: Are you referring to the `std::map` or suggesting to implement a hash map? This is a `C` question, not `C++` and I think implementing a hash map might be more difficult than the approach by @japreiss and not much more efficient.